# jsonp and zendframe work 1 doesnt return any thing(im working with phonegap and use Zend as a service)

Tags: zend-framework, cordova, jsonp

this is my zend controller
[image]

and this is how i called my service
[image]

please teach me how. it's important ! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bit of extra work with what you have there. I've done it this way in both ZF1 and ZF2:

PHP

```
// notice 'searchteams' is lowercased. There's been problems in the past
// when camelcasing action names, by default I believe ZF is looking for
// a lowercase action name unless you've configured it otherwise
public function searchteamsAction()
{
    // make sure this is an ajax request (this is a method I usually write, if 
    // Zend has one you could use that here)
    if ($this->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        // instantiate model, get the results, good
        // disabling view and layout, good

        // headers, never really had an issue that needed the headers to be set here
        // would simply have..
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
}
```

JS: in the success method in the AJAX call, I'd do this:

```
success : function (data){   
    // parse the json
    var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(parsed_data);

    // do stuff with parsed_data
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your datas with a `return var_dump($res);` before `$this->_response->setHeader(...`
2. if you have datas, try to add `$this->_response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true);`
3. If not work, try to replace

   ```
   $this->_response->setHeader(...);
   $this->_response->setHeader(...);
   $this->_response->setHeader(...);
   $this->_response->setHeader(...);
   ```

   and `echo Zend_Json::encode($res);`
   by only

   ```
   return $this->_helper->json($res);
   ```

You can also see the error on the side of jQuery with something like:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert("error status: " + status);
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

I hope it will help you :)